# Copy rows, chosen by checkbox, to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that contains a search engine. After you type your search; a filter generates with the search criteria.

After having the filtered results; I want the user to select some of the rows to copy to another sheet.
I am thinking if I there was a checkbox for each row (before the filter); then from the filtered results, the user would check the needed rows.

This is the search box:

```vb
Sub SearchBox()
    'PURPOSE: Filter Data on User-Determined Column & Text/Numerical value
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com
    
    Dim myButton As OptionButton
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim ButtonName As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim myField As Long
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim mySearch As Variant
    
    'Load Sheet into A Variable
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    
    'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
    On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
      
    'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
    Set DataRange = sht.Range("A7:D1000") 'Cell Range
    'Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("Table 2").Range 'Table
    
    'Retrieve User's Search Input
     mySearch = sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form
    'mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control
    'mySearch = sht.Range("A1").Value 'Cell Input
       
    'Determine if user is searching for number or text
    If IsNumeric(mySearch) = True Then
        SearchString = "=" & mySearch
    Else
        SearchString = "=*" & mySearch & "*"
    End If
        
   'Loop Through Option Buttons
    For Each myButton In sht.OptionButtons
        If myButton.Value = 1 Then
            ButtonName = myButton.Text
            Exit For
        End If
    Next myButton
       
    'Determine Filter Field
    On Error GoTo HeadingNotFound
    myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
       
    'Filter Data
    DataRange.AutoFilter _
      Field:=myField, _
      Criteria1:=SearchString, _
      Operator:=xlAnd
      
    'Clear Search Field
    sht.Shapes("UserSearch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "" 'Control Form
    'sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
    'sht.Range("A1").Value = "" 'Cell Input
      
    Exit Sub
    
'ERROR HANDLERS
HeadingNotFound:
    MsgBox "The column heading [" & ButtonName & "] was not found in cells " & DataRange.Rows(1).Address & ". " & _
      vbNewLine & "Please check for possible typos.", vbCritical, "Header Name Not Found!"
      
End Sub
```

This is to clear the filter:

```vb
Sub ClearFilter()
    'PURPOSE: Clear all filter rules
    
    'Clear filters on ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For demonstration purposes I will go ahead and assume your data setup looks something like that:

[image]

The data is being filtered from your existing code.

I have added the checkboxes that you suggested, one in each row.

For the following code to work, it is important that the checkboxes are `Form Controls` and not `ActiveX controls`.

It is also crucial that the `Move and size with cells` option has been activated for each checkbox. This will "bind" in a way the checkbox to the cell you place it in, meaning that when the corresponding row is being filtered out, the checkbox is hidden as well.

```
Sub copySelected()
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim shtDestination As Worksheet
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim cb As CheckBox
Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of Source Worksheet") 'where the data is
Set shtDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of Destination Worksheet") 'where the selected rows should be copied
For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes 'loop through all the checkboxes
    If cb.Value = 1 Then 'if the checkbox has been selected by the user then...
        shtSource.Range("B" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row, "D" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row).Copy '...copy the corresponding range of data...
        With shtDestination
            .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '...and paste it to the first empty row in the destination sheet
        End With
    End If
Next cb
End Sub
```